# How run/debug website which includes ReactJS components, but are included through their compiled javascript files

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner in ReactJS, webpacks, NodeJS. I have a website which includes two main react components. These components are not directly included in the website, they are first built to produce .js files and then included like this:

1) In index.html file there is a search component in react and included to the .html file like this at the end of the file

```
<script src="assets/build/search.min.js"></script>
```

2) In post.html, same thing is happening:

```
<script src="assets/build/post.min.js"></script>
```

When I try to run this simply through index.html all the website works except the react components. I need a way to run and debug this on my local machine. Please advise.

Comment: define "doesn't work". Are there errors being thrown in the browser console?

Comment: there are no such errors regarding the react files. everything is working, but the react components are not being shown

Comment: it's very unusual for react component to entirely not show up and not throw errors (like not finding the dom node to attach to). can you show the index.html file and also the code that calls `ReactDOM.render` ?

Comment: index.html file contains nothing but plain html and javascript, but at the end a javascript file is included like so as mentioned in the questioned. This javascript file is a compiled version of the react file 'main.js' if you want I can include it's code in my question as well. This search.min.js was built through 'npm run-scripts build' command through node. I cannot understand why it is not working on my side.